# Exponential Ingratiation solving

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

[image]

In the below definite integral, I am confused with the result, how they get 1/a  for the integral part?

Can we do  in this way? 
$$\int_\infty^{-\infty} e^{-2a|x|}dx 
= \frac{1}{-2a} [e^{-\infty } -  e^ { -\infty}]=0 ??? $$

Comment: No.  Take note of the absolute value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2a|x|}dx = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2a|x|}dx = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2ax}dx = \frac{2}{-2a}\left[e^{-2ax}\right]_{0}^{\infty} = -\frac{1}{a}\left(\frac{1}{e^{\infty}}-\frac{1}{e^0}\right)$

above we have used the formula $\displaystyle \bullet\; \int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx = 2\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx\;,$ If $f(-x) = f(x).$

and $|x| = x\;,$ If $x>0$